# Search for value in 3rd level of a multidimensional array and return flattened, qualifying data sets

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering, flatten

I am trying to search for qualifying entries in a multidimensional array and return one or more data sets as flattened, associative subarrays.

Sample input:

```
[
    [
        'name' => 'Dick Jansen',
        'matchedMovie' => [
            [
                'nameMovie' => 'Saw',
                'genre' => 'Horror',
                'patheMovie' => 'Texas Chainsaw 3D',
                'patheMovieGenre' => 'Horror',
                'score' => '100.00',
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Jim Scott',
        'matchedMovie' => [
            [
                'nameMovie' => 'Shooter',
                'genre' => 'Action, Thriller',
                'patheMovie' => 'The Shining',
                'patheMovieGenre' => 'Horror, Suspense/Thriller',
                'score' => '52.38',
            ],                
            [
                'nameMovie' => 'Resident Evil Movie',
                'genre' => 'Action/Horror',
                'patheMovie' => 'Texas Chainsaw 3D',
                'patheMovieGenre' => 'Horror',
                'score' => '63.16',
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

I want to search on the `patheMovie` values (like 'The Shining') and get the parent array's `name` plus only the `matchedMovie` array with the matched `patheMovie` value.

My code:

```
$search = 'Texas Chainsaw 3D';

$sorted = false;
foreach ($sorted as $n => $c)
    if (in_array($search, $c)) {
        $cluster = $n;
        break;
    }
```

If I search for `The Shining`, the result should be:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Jim Scott',
    'nameMovie' => 'Shooter',
    'genre' => 'Action, Thriller',
    'patheMovie' => 'The Shining',
    'patheMovieGenre' => 'Horror, Suspense/Thriller',
    'score' => '52.38',
  ),
)
```

If I search for `Texas Chainsaw 3D`, then the result should be:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Dick Jansen',
    'nameMovie' => 'Saw',
    'genre' => 'Horror',
    'patheMovie' => 'Texas Chainsaw 3D',
    'patheMovieGenre' => 'Horror',
    'score' => '100.00',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Jim Scott',
    'nameMovie' => 'Resident Evil Movie',
    'genre' => 'Action/Horror',
    'patheMovie' => 'Texas Chainsaw 3D',
    'patheMovieGenre' => 'Horror',
    'score' => '63.16',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This solution will depend into two conjugated loops.

```
<?php
function searchIt($arr, $searchItem){
$result = array();
$resultIndex = 0;
for ($i =0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
 for ($j = 0; $j < count($arr[$i]['matchedMovie']); $j++){
  if ($arr[$i]['matchedMovie'][$j]['patheMovie'] == $searchItem){
   $result[$resultIndex]['name'] = $arr[$i]['name'];
    foreach ($arr[$i]['matchedMovie'][$j] as $key => $value){
     $result[$resultIndex][$key] = $value;
   }
    $resultIndex++;
  }
 } 
}
return $result;
}
?>
```

#### [phpfiddle demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/xmt-j9u)

Comment: If you are sure that the pathMovie value could not be repeated in a sub array (second level array) you are able to use break in the inner loop to increase performance.

Comment: [I would not solve this problem using 3 loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77123768/2943403) (...or use `for()` and `count()` calls)

Comment: @mickmackusa could you explain why?

Comment: Because there are only two nested subarrays to iterate, this task can be accomplished in just 2 loops (as shown by my linked answer).  I find calling `count()` on every iteration (despite the count never changing) to be poor practice.  I'd say call `count()` only the first time and cache the value, but `foreach()` is a cleaner way of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but this should work:

```
function findYourGuy($array, $searchTerm) {
    $searchTerm = 'The Shining'; // testing purpose only
    foreach($array as $personArray) {
        $matchedMovies = $personArray['matchedMovie'];
        $name = $personArray['name'];
        foreach($matchedMovies as $matchedMovie) {
            if($matchedMovie['patheMovie'] == $searchTerm) {
                return array('name' => $name, 'matchedMovie' => $matchedMovie)
            }
        }
    }
    return false; //no result
}
```

Comment: thank you for your anwser. this helps alot, problem is only when there are 2 matched in the array. Like if i search for 'Texas Chainsaw 3D', i only get one name back. But i want to get two.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [array_filter](https://www.php.net/array_filter). Something along the lines

```
$movieName = 'The shining';
$result = array_filter($movies, filterCallback);

function filterCallback($var)
{
  foreach($var['matchedMovie'] as $movie) {
    if($movie['PatheMovie'] == $movieName) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This unexplained script doesn't not work because of a fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

Because this task requires not only filtering the input array data, but also restructuring (flattening) the qualifying rows, you cannot simply use `array_filter()` or `array_map()` as a solution in one pass.  For this reason, just use classic loops, then push the flattened data if the data set qualifies.

I am going to use "array destructuring" in the signature of the outer loop to enjoy convenient variables.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/lXKQf))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($movies as ['name' => $name, 'matchedMovie' => $matches]) {
    foreach ($matches as $entry) {
        if ($movieName === $entry['patheMovie']) {
            $result[] = ['name' => $name] + $entry;
        }
    }
}
var_export($result)
```